# SQL statement fails in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB  rest of my connstring.... ");
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("Update tblImages SET Name=@name, Descript=@descript WHERE Id=@id", connection);
update.Parameters.Add("name", TextBox3.Text);
update.Parameters.Add("descript",TextBox4.Text);
update.Parameters.Add("id",id);
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting an error when executing `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: you are getting *what* error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `connection.Open()` before `update.ExecuteNonQuery()`. You also need to use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to make sure `connection` is closed after `update.ExecuteNonQuery()` is executed. The parameter names in `update.Parameters.Add(...)` method are also wrong, you forgot to add `@`

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB  rest of my connstring.... "))
{
    using (SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("Update tblImages SET Name = @name, Descript = @descript WHERE Id = @id", connection))
    {
        update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", TextBox3.Text));
        update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descript", TextBox4.Text));
        update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

        connection.Open();
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are missing the '@' symbol in your add parameter statement. You're also using add and not `AddWithValue`.

Try changing it to this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB  rest of my connstring.... ");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("Update tblImages SET Name=@name, Descript=@descript WHERE Id=@id", connection);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox3.Text);
update.Parameters.ADdWithValue("@descript", TextBox4.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice I also changed the code to open the connection that you've created.